# 'which' usage - does it carry over in this instance?

Tags: relative-clauses, coordination

> "a town which bordered the school and **which** was exclusively populated by immigrants"

I didn't put the second "which" in at first, and then felt it was necessary. 
Can anyone confirm that it's needed?

Answer (score 2):

I can confirm that it's useful.

There are two relative clauses.   Each clause has its own verb.   Those two verbs are very different.  The verb "bordered" employs the active voice and has a direct object.  The verb "was populated" employs the passive voice and has no object.

These differences make it difficult to treat them as elements of a compound predicate.   Each relates to its subject in a different way.   The version of your nominative phrase which uses two instances of "which" is easier to understand.

If the verbs had more in common, a compound predicate would make more sense.   For instance, "a town which bordered the school and housed only immigrants".

Please note, although you have two clauses, your entire phrase is not a complete sentence.   It is a grammatically correct noun phrase, but it is only a phrase.